# Establishing the concept of epimorphism in category theory from surjective function in set theory

Tags: category-theory

I was reading [here](http://jtdaugherty.github.io/posts/epimorphisms-and-surjectivity.html) to understand how to establish the concept of  epimorphism in category theory from surjective function in set theory, got stuck [here](https://youtu.be/O2lZkr-aAqk?list=PLbgaMIhjbmEnaH_LTkxLI7FMa2HsnawM_&t=2494).

Definition: A function $f:A\to B$ is an epimorphism if for all sets $Z$ and all functions $a_1,a_2:B\to Z$,
$a_1\circ f=a_2\circ f\implies a_1=a_2$.

If $f:A\to B$ is an epimorphism, then by the above definition we can choose two functions $a_1,a_2:B\to Z$ as described above such that $a_1\circ f=a_2\circ f\implies a_1=a_2$.

Now assume that $f$ is not surjective. Then there is some $b\in B$ such that $b \not\in\text{Im}f$. If so, it's possible that $a_1(b)\ne a_2(b)$ so the implication $a_1=a_2$ does not hold. Therefore, for the implication to hold, $f$ must be surjective.

**Question:** So $b\in B$ but $b$ is not an image of $f$  i.e.  $b\not\in\text{Im}f$ . How it leads to $a_1(b)\ne a_2(b)$ ? If we assumed $a_1=a_2$ then why would they produce different results?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You don't have a problem here with definitions but with *logic* and *quantifiers*. To make a contradiction, you need to prove that $f$ cannot be epimorphism. This means: *there exists a set $Z$* and *there exist $a_1, a_2:B\to Z$* such that $a_1\circ f=a_2\circ f$ but *not* $a_1=a_2$. So, let's prove that they exist by *constructing* them. Let $Z$ be any set of at least two elements, say $Z=\{0, 1\}$. Let $a_1$ map the entire set $B$ to $0$. Let $a_2$ map the entire set $B$ to $0$, **except** $b$, which is mapped to $1$. There you go: $a_1\ne a_2$. Show that $a_1\circ f=a_2\circ f$ still!